# How to find all the number in a given range that can be divided by 8?

Tags: python

I'm a begginner to python and I was trying to find all the numbers that can be divided by 8

For example:

```
A range from 0-300
```

Comment: `range(0, 300, 8)` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of numbers between two numbers, use the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function.

To check if a number can be divided by 8 (and I assume no remainder), use the modulo operator. For example:

```
>>> 4 % 3
1
>>> 16 % 8
0
```

This returns the remainder of dividing the first number by the second.

---

Now try write some code. If you're having some trouble, feel free to ask another question showing *what you have tried*.

Comment: also in case you don't know what modulo is, it returns the _remainder_ of a division equation. So, if a number is evenly divisible by 8, then the modulo would return 0, else it will return something other than zero. Good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this by checking:

```
for each number from 0 to 300, test if divisible by 8
```

say

```
0 is divisible by 8
All numbers bigger by a factor of 8 (8, 16, 24, 32, ...) are also divisible by 8
```

which leads you to the obvious

```
step from 0 to 300 in increments of 8
```

which we can do with range. Eg. to find all numbers from 0 to 50 (not including 50) which are divisible by 5:

```
# range(start, stop, step)
range(0, 50, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the modulo operator like this

```
80%8
>>> 0

160%8
>>> 0
```

it will return zero if the number is divisible with no remainder

or you can use the step option for `range()` by doing `range(0, 300, 8)`

[More on operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

Comment: Please try not to just show the answer.

Comment: You're right i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would give you a list of the numbers between 0 and 300 divisible by 8:

```
[x for x in xrange(300) if x % 8 == 0]
```

Comment: Please try not to just show the answer.